# SPI and I2C interface on Pi

Tags: i2c, interfacing

I was going through this [article](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/)

Under the heading "Real Time performance constraints" it talks about the constraints and says that "This means that you should not expect to get real-time performance or real-time timing constraints from such programs."

My questions are

1. What's the solution of this problem in Pi's context. How can we make this a part of the kernel ?
2. How in other devices, like mobile phones, such interfaces work in real-time.Say the applications and games designed using accelerometer on a mobile phone reacts in real-time .

Comment: What do you mean by "this problem in Pi's context" in your first question? Can you define more clearly what you see as the problem, and what you would consider as a solution? I think the line "please don't expect to get exactly the time delay you request" is what worries you; right?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question: It probably depends on your definition of "real time". I think they mean "there is no guaranteed response time", but in practice the time is "usually finite" - of the order of ms. Which is enough for 99% of applications in gaming etc.